# Create a REST-ful api in Node.js for notifications

Tags: node.js, rest, notifications

I'm a newbie in Node.js and after doing initial learning on Node.js, I find it rather confusing to find out any best practices. My project requires to build a real-time notification system such that, when something happens at the server side or any of the connected clients, a notification can pop up at all connected clients. I couldn't find any official recommendations on what's the best approach and tools to take. I saw there are various frameworks written in Node.js seem able to do the job, but I'm hoping some one can give me some direction.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Angularfire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html) if you want to code less.

You can create real-time apps without a backend part like so: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/master/examples/firebase-angular/js/app.js

Note, this is a Q&A site. Ask a question next time. "Please direct me" is not allowed to ask here.